# Php jquery is not auto refreshing the div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to auto refresh a div which contains the Sub Total of item but its not working/refreshing the div.
I tried many things but its not ready to work.

I am refreshing the Grand Total which updates/refreshes perfectly fine and if i removes a sub item of a main item it changes the Grand Total fine but does not change the Sub Total of the items.

[image]

I am using the separate refresh code for the grand total.

My codes are below:

**index.php**

```
<?php
$order_temp =   mysql_query("select * from temp_cart where ses_mem='".$ses_mem."' order by id");

while ($torder = mysql_fetch_array($order_temp)) {
$prITTD     =   $torder['id'];
$prITTC     =   $torder['item_id'];
?>

<script>
function refreshTable() {
    $('.tableHolder').load('itemtotal_cart_checkout.php?item_id=' + <?php echo $prITTC; ?>, function() {
       setTimeout(function () { refreshTable() }, 1000);
    });
}
</script>

<div class="amount tableHolder">
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

**itemtotal_cart_checkout.php**

```
<?php
@session_start();
include('inc/db.php');
$ses_mem    =   $_SESSION['ses_user_id'];
//session_id();
$getItem    =   $_GET['item_id'];

$order_temp =   "select * from temp_cart where item_id='".$getItem."' AND ses_mem='".$ses_mem."' order by id";
$tordera = $db->query($order_temp);
while ($torder = $tordera -> fetch_assoc()){


    $prITTD     =   $torder['id'];
    $prITTC     =   $torder['item_id'];
    $prIDTC     =   $torder['price_id'];
    $qtyT       =   $torder['qty'];
?>
<span class="amount">
<?php   
$chTPaa =   mysql_query("
select choice_id
FROM temp_choices
WHERE item_id = '$getItem'
AND ses_mem = '$ses_mem'
group by choice_id
");
$numRows    =   mysql_num_rows($chTPaa);

while ($chGETaa =   mysql_fetch_assoc($chTPaa)){
$temp[] = $chGETaa['choice_id'];

$thelist    =   implode(",",$temp);
}
if ($numRows > 0){
$sumToCq1   =   mysql_query("
SELECT sum(p.price) as sTotal, t.item_id as item_id
FROM temp_cart as t, temp_choices tc, choice_price p
WHERE t.ses_mem='".$ses_mem."'
AND t.item_id = '".$getItem."'
AND tc.item_id = '".$getItem."'
AND p.id = tc.choice_id
");
$sumToC1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sumToCq1);
$sumToNR = count($sumToCq1);
$choiceOptionsTotal1    =   $sumToC1['sTotal'];
    $tsl    = ($choiceOptionsTotal1*$qtyT)+($qtyT*$prIDTC);
}else{
    $tsl    = $qtyT*$prIDTC;
}

//number_format($tsl, 3);
$altsl  = number_format($tsl, 3, '.', '');
echo $altsl;
?>
</span>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: function refreshTable() contains javascript/jquery and not php.
It seems like you are running it within a php function ?
Script should run in <script></script> tags

Comment: @JPJens  im using the <script> sorry i did nt pasted here. its not working

Comment: You should paste the full code, or at least correct the obvious errors, such as php close tag etc.
refreshTable(); is declared, but not being run anywhere ?

Comment: @JPJens corrected the errors u said. yes it is not being run anywhere.

Comment: Well if you want refreshTable() to run, then you should run it in the <script> tag after the function.
Besides from that you are declaring a function within a loop. It will just be redeclared over and over

Comment: @JPJens well i tried as u said but now it is showing the last records value with all rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125797/discussion-between-fahad-almehaini-and-jpjens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to update individual divs as you are running it within a loop.

Try something like this

```
<?php
$order_temp =   mysql_query("select * from temp_cart where ses_mem='".$ses_mem."' order by id");
while ($torder = mysql_fetch_array($order_temp)) {
    $prITTD     =   $torder['id'];
    $prITTC     =   $torder['item_id'];
    $script    .= "refreshTable(".$prITTC.");";
    ?>
    <div class="amount tableHolder_<?=$prITTC;?>"></div>
    <?
}
?>

<script>
  function refreshTable(id) {
      $('.tableHolder_'+id).load('itemtotal_cart_checkout.php?item_id='+id, function() {
         setTimeout(function () { refreshTable(id) }, 1000);
      });
  }
  <?=$script;?>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your kind answer (Y)